# Sending mail using SendGrid and Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, smtp, sendgrid

I'm trying to send email using SendGrid service using Spring, but I'm always getting this error: `Unauthenticated senders not allowed`.

Here's my java:

```
MimeMessageHelper message = new MimeMessageHelper(mimeMessage, isMultipart, CharEncoding.UTF_8);
message.setTo(to);
message.setFrom(from);
message.setSubject(subject);
message.setText(content, isHtml);
javaMailSender.send(mimeMessage);
```

...and my yml:

```
    mail:
    host: smtp.sendgrid.net
    username: myusername
    password: mypassword
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made it work with explicitly telling the sender that the request must be made with authentication, like this:

```
MimeMessageHelper message = new MimeMessageHelper(mimeMessage, isMultipart, CharEncoding.UTF_8);
message.setTo(to);
message.setFrom(from);
message.setSubject(subject);
message.setText(content, isHtml);

Properties mailProperties = new Properties();
mailProperties.put(MAIL_TRANSPORT_PROTOCOL, "smtp");
mailProperties.put(MAIL_SMTP_AUTH, "true");

javaMailSender.setJavaMailProperties(mailProperties);
javaMailSender.send(mimeMessage);
```